# Handle Synchronous Request Failure on EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

**Requirements:**

1. Build and Host a web service for a Data Transformation application on Cloud.
2. Hosted Application will get request from clients as REST Request – Client will send a string which we need to transform and send them back. (synchronous)
3. Designed system should be Fail safe, resilient and should be up 24*7.

**My Question :**
Our EC2 are running in Auto Scaling group, they will shutdown and start depending on load. Lets say if client request is in process of being executed in an EC2 and in between suddenly the EC2 goes down and the client request is lost. How to handle this ? I don't think it is a good idea ask our client to set a Time out and send us the request again if they donot get response in some defined period. We want to handle this functionality at our end.

Constructive Feedback and Suggestions are welcome.
Thanks for your time.

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/config-conn-drain.html

Comment: @MarkB Thanks for the link, that was helpful. Lets take a scenario where the EC2 goes down while processing a request due to some hardware or technical issue then is it possible to retrieve the lost request ? Is it possible to store the REST request somewhere and resend the request to other EC2 in cluster.

Comment: No that isn't possible.

Comment: Thanks @MarkB for the clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We want to handle this functionality at our end.

Having load-balanced auto-scaling group is pretty much resilient, an instance should not receive a request when it is about to be shut down (as far I know it is removed from the target scaling group). Now we are talking about request taking reasonable short time.

You cannot do much more about on the infrastructure level

> I don't think it is a good idea ask our client to set a Time out and send us the request again

retries are pretty common, it's even part of an assumption that network is not reliable (mainly using (micro)services with dynamic scaling)

> Is it possible to store the REST request somewhere and resend the request to other EC2 in cluster.

That what SQS is for .. in theory.

One approach is asking the client to retry in case of certain failure types (timeout, HTTP 503, .. ).

Another way would be using some sort of reliable delivery (such as SQS), but for the price of performance (and still the network may fail)

Comment: Thanks a lot @gusto2 for clarification :)